# How to bend a short piece of EMT conduit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, emt

I need to make a 10 inch wide U type bend on a 1/2 inch EMT pipe.  The piece is about 20 inches long.  I got one end to bend 90 degrees fine.  But I'm struggling with the other end.  I got it probably at around 65 degrees and it won't bend any further.  There is no lever.  It just kind of rolls over at this point.

Any tips or tricks on how to get the second end to 90 degrees?

**EDIT:**  I am using the klein bender tool.  This is for electrical.  I got a tip of a pipe sticking out and a box is about 10 inches away from it.  The pipe is drywalled in.  I can't get to it unless I start breaking the drywall.  Another way would be to run a flex and be done with it.  But I had this piece of conduit EMT which looked like it could get the job done.  So just wondering, how can I get that perfect U out of it.  It seems to be too short.

Comment: For electrical? It sounds like you are doing something you should not.  For general fabrication because EMT is cheap pipe?  Hossfeld Bender.  Soon you'll be able to buy robots to do that, but they'll really like blackjack and hookers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bender_(Futurama)

Comment: You do not have actual pipe bending tool ? just using pure muscle craft

Comment: Sorry, I am using a bender tool.  Should've stated that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general trick is to bend and then cut, rather than starting with a short piece that limits your ability to work the bender. You need a certain amount of "stub" for the bender to hold onto.

If you have enough to grab with the bender, but are having trouble controlling the tiny thing as you bend, which I infer from:

> It just kind of rolls over at this point.

Then clamp the bend on the other side in a vise to hold the bottom of the U upright, or hold it between two clamped boards if you lack a vise.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not have a bending tool, you are using pure muscle craft to do the bending.

For that I recommend you use a pipe twice the length then you need, then cut it to size after bending.

The problem is you started with bending one end while you still had enough pipe to use as leverage. Once bend now you are left with shorter pice that would require much more force to bend.

You could try inserting an extension in to the pipe so to have more leverage.

This calc tool might help

[bender](https://makerpipe.com/pages/how-to-make-circles-with-conduit-incremental-bending-calculator)

Comment: I am using klein bender tool.  I made an edit to the original post.  I basically had this piece of EMT pipe about 20 inches long laying around.  Thought I could make that work.

Comment: @Dimskiy then my answer is wrong. So what is not working ?

Comment: @Dimskiy making sure your question is correct means you don’t waste people’s time - especially when you are the one asking for help.